# options_for_select and i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

Our Rails app has a list of valid language code stored in an array.

```
LANGUAGES = [:en,:fr,:es,:tr,:pt,:de,:it,:ga,:gr]
```

The are translated via a locales file.

```
  en: 'English'
  de: 'German'
  ga: 'Irish'
  fr: 'French'
  etc.
```

I would like to display the translated string in `options_for_select`, but this code is passing the translated value to the controller, eg: 'French'.

```rb
<%= f.select :language, options_for_select(t(LanguageName::LANGUAGES), f.object.language || t('fr')) %>
```

Note that this select will default the select to 'fr' only if it is not already populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the document here: https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

```
options_for_select({ "Basic" => "$20", "Plus" => "$40" }, "$40")
  <option value="$20">Basic</option>\n<option value="$40" selected="selected">Plus</option>
```

Assuming in your locale file the name of the languages is as follows:

```
en:
  languages:
    en: 'English'
    de: 'German'
    ga: 'Irish'
    fr: 'French'
```

I'm thinking what you need is something like the following:

```
f.select :language, options_for_select(
  LanguageName::LANGUAGES.map { |lang| [t("languages.#{lang}"), lang] }.to_h
  f.object.language || t('languages.fr')
)
```

Of course it's always better to extract the method out into a helper file:

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def map_locale_names(locale)
    LanguageName::LANGUAGES.map { |lang| [t("languages.#{lang}", locale: locale), lang] }.to_h
  end
end
```

so that your method will become the following:

```
f.select :language, options_for_select(
  map_locale_names(locale: params[:locale]),
  f.object.language || t('languages.fr')
)
```

Hope this helps.